# My player can go through floor and walls when swinging

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a Spiderman game and have added swinging to it. When the player swings however, they are able to go through walls and floor. Here is a video of it happening:

https://www.reddit.com/r/Unity3D/comments/waanl9/my_player_can_go_through_walls_when_swinging_info/

Here is the code used for the swinging:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[System.Serializable]

public class Pendulum
{
public Transform bob_tr;

public Tether tether;

public Arm arm;

public Bob bob;

public bool Swinging;

Vector3 previousPosition;

public GameObject Player;


public void Initialize()
{
    bob_tr.transform.position = Player.transform.position;
    bob_tr.transform.parent = tether.tether_tr;
    Swinging = false;
}

public Vector3 MoveBob(Vector3 pos , float time)
{

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        Swinging = true;
    }
    else if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
    {
        Swinging = false;
    }

    if(Swinging == false)
    {
        arm.length = Vector3.Distance(bob_tr.transform.localPosition, tether.position);
    }
    
    bob.velocity += GetConstrainedVelocity(pos , previousPosition , time);
    bob.ApplyGravity();
    bob.ApplyDamping();
    bob.CapMaxSpeed();
    
    pos += bob.velocity * time;
    
    if(Vector3.Distance(pos , tether.position) < arm.length)
    {
        pos = Vector3.Normalize(pos - tether.position) * arm.length;
        return pos;
    }
    
    previousPosition = pos;
    
    return pos;
}

public Vector3 MoveBob(Vector3 pos , Vector3 prevPos , float time)
{

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        Swinging = true;
    }
    else if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
    {
        Swinging = false;
    }

    if(Swinging == false)
    {
        arm.length = Vector3.Distance(bob_tr.transform.localPosition, tether.position);
    }

    bob.velocity += GetConstrainedVelocity(pos , prevPos , time);
    bob.ApplyGravity();
    bob.ApplyDamping();
    bob.CapMaxSpeed();
    
    pos += bob.velocity * time;
    

    
    previousPosition = pos;
    
    return pos;
}

public Vector3 GetConstrainedVelocity(Vector3 currentPos, Vector3 previousPosition , float time)
{
    float distanceToTether;
    Vector3 constrainedPosition;
    Vector3 predictedPosition;
    
    
    distanceToTether = Vector3.Distance(currentPos , tether.position);
    
    if(distanceToTether > arm.length)
    {
        constrainedPosition = Vector3.Normalize(currentPos - tether.position) * arm.length;
        predictedPosition = (constrainedPosition - previousPosition) / time;
        return predictedPosition;
    }
    return Vector3.zero;
}


public Vector3 Fall(Vector3 pos , float time)
{
    arm.length = Vector3.Distance(bob_tr.transform.localPosition, tether.position);

    bob.ApplyGravity();
    bob.ApplyDamping();
    bob.CapMaxSpeed();
    
    pos += bob.velocity * time;
    return pos;
}

}
```

Comment: Are you moving Bob by setting any positions directly?  Can you show where `MoveBob` is called, how the return value is used, and perhaps what the `Bob` class looks like?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. Yes I am moving the bob by setting it's position directly. Now that I think, that would cause the issue wouldn't it. Because it will move into walls. I'm currently at work, I will send the Bob script when I get home. Thank for help :)